# how to implement floodfill algorithm using fabricjs?

Tags: canvas, fabricjs, flood-fill, fabricjs2

I have an algorithm for Floodfilling a canvas. Im trying to incorporate this with `fabricJS`. So here is the dilemna.... I create a `fabric.Canvas()`. Which creates a wrapper canvas and also an upper-canvas canvas. I click on the canvas to apply my `Floodfill()`. This works fine and applies my color. But as soon as i go to drag my canvas objects around, or add additional objects to the canvas, the color disappears and looks like it resets of sort.

Comment: share your code - it will help someone help you.

Comment: Not really into fabric, but IMM the best would be to put your ImageData over an offscreen native canvas, and somehow add this native canvas into your scene. Though I'm not sure if fabric.Image does accept a native canvas...